# GridLayout’s rowOrderPreserved and columnOrderPreserved

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

Can someone please explain  what `GridLayout`’s `rowOrderPreserved` and `columnOrderPreserved` mean?

I don't understand the docs. What is the difference between setting the value to true or false. An illustration wil be very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following piece of code with `GridLayout`:

```
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true"
    android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="true"
    android:columnCount="4"
    >

    <TextView
        android:text="Email setup"
        android:textSize="32dip"
        android:layout_columnSpan="4"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="Email address:"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        />

    <EditText
        android:ems="10"
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="Password:"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        />

    <EditText
        android:ems="8"
        />



    <Button
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="3"
        />
</GridLayout>
```

This xml generates a view as follows in which the 'Next'-button is outside of the screen:

[image]

This is because the first `EditText` element defines the width of the second column. When defining the 'Next' button in the fourth column, it has to be right of the second column.

Now, changing the attribute `columnOrderPreserved` to `false` gives android the *liberty to place the horizontal column boundaries in whatever order best fits the given constraints.* (See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html#setColumnOrderPreserved(boolean))) The result is as in this image:

[image]