# Need list with column headers and different column widths on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

Like this:

```
Code     Product Description                 Stock    Tel  
P1234    Portland Cement 25kg                70       0208 1234567  
P4321    MGM Sharp Sand Bulk Bag 800kg       3        0799 98765433
```

The variable-length product description may be up to 45 characters.

Will use the wider horizontal display on the mobile for this.

I checked and found gridview does not support different-width columns.
From what I understand it may be the same for listview.

Is there a way without using x,y for positioning the columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with a [`GridLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout) or (possibly) with a [`TableLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout).

There is also `GridView`, but as far as I know every cell in a `GridView` must have the same size with every other. I don't know if a cell could span multiple rows/columns in a `GridView` though, but even if it can and since every cell must be the same size, then you would have to calculate how many cells your data would require for each entry. So I would suggest going with the previous 2 options.

Finally, `RecyclerView`s can arrange `View`s in a grid (via `GridLayoutManager`), but I am not aware if it can fit your requirements (such as variable size for each cell), so I am just leaving it here in case you want to look at it as another possible option.

Here is an example implementation with a `GridLayout`:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static void addTextViews(final ViewGroup viewGroup,
                                     final String... text) {
        final Context ctx = viewGroup.getContext();
        for (final String t: text) {
            final TextView view = new TextView(ctx);
            view.setText(t);
            viewGroup.addView(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final GridLayout viewGroup = new GridLayout(this);

        //Configure grid:
        viewGroup.setColumnCount(4); //Wrap every 4 columns.
        viewGroup.setUseDefaultMargins(true); //Insert default space between cells.
        viewGroup.setAlignmentMode(GridLayout.ALIGN_BOUNDS); //Required by 'setUseDefaultMargins(true)' documentation.

        //Populate the grid:
        addTextViews(viewGroup, "Code", "Product Description", "Stock", "Tel");
        addTextViews(viewGroup, "P1234", "Portland Cement 25kg", "70", "0208 1234567");
        addTextViews(viewGroup, "P4321", "MGM Sharp Sand Bulk Bag 800kg", "3", "0799 98765433");
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; ++i)
            addTextViews(viewGroup, Integer.toString(i), "MGM Sharp Sand Bulk Bag 800kg......", Integer.toOctalString(5 * i), "0799 98765433");

        //Add the grid to scroll views:
        final HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
        horizontalScrollView.addView(viewGroup);
        final ScrollView verticalScrollView = new ScrollView(this);
        verticalScrollView.addView(horizontalScrollView);

        setContentView(verticalScrollView);
    }
}
```

The `TextView`s are added to the grid starting from the top-left cell and going to the right until `4` columns are filled, in which case the next `TextView`s will go in subsequent rows following the same pattern. This behaviour is because of the combination of horizontal orientation (which is the default value for the `GridLayout`), together with setting the column count to `4`. By default, each cell spans a single row and a single column.

The `GridLayout` does not have built in support for scrolling, but you can add it to both a `HorizontalScrollView` and a vertical `ScrollView`, as demonstrated in the above sample code, in order to enable scrolling.

You can always look more information about those `ViewGroup`s in their documentation.

Comment: Many thanks for showing how to use GridLayout for different width column data.
I have read the GridLayout documentation, but I don't understand how/why it works. 
I was hoping for a simple rule like 'width of a column is the width of the
widest data in a column' or 'different column widths are allowed', but could not find that. 

Perhaps the column width is decided by the ALIGN_BOUNDS constant which says:
'alignment is made between the edges of each component's raw view boundary'.
Still lost, what alignment? Alignment in relation to what?  I want to understand this.
Anyone?

Comment: No problem. Please (re)read carefully the section [Excess Space Distribution](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout#excess-space-distribution) of the documentation. Start from there, then read [`setColumnOrderPreserved`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout#setColumnOrderPreserved(boolean)) to achieve different cell dimensions per row/column (same applies with `setRowOrderPreserved`) ([example explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221412/gridlayout-s-roworderpreserved-and-columnorderpreserved)).

Comment: As for the alignment mode `ALIGN_BOUNDS` the documentation explains as *...the area delimited by the component's: top, left, bottom and right properties.* (each `View` has those properties, which are then taken into account when added to the `GridLayout`) ([example explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395773/gridlayout-align-children-within-column)).